# Theorem 17 Corollary 2, Section 3.6 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, dual-spaces

**Definition:** Let $(V,F,+_V,\cdot_V)$ and $(F,F,+_F,\cdot_F)$ be vector space over field $F$. Then $V^{**}$ $=(V^*)^*$ $=L(V^*,F)$ $=L(L(V,F),F)$ is called **double dual space** of $V$.

---

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over the field $F$. Each basis for $V^*$ is the dual of some basis for $V$.

**My attempt:** Since $\mathrm{dim}(V)=n\in \Bbb{N}$, we have $\mathrm{dim}(V^*)$ $= \mathrm{dim}(V)$ $=n$. Let $B^*=\{f_1,…,f_n\}$ be a basis of $V^*$. Let $B^{**}=\{L_1,…,L_n\}$ be dual basis of $B^*$. So $L_i(f_j)=\delta_{ij}$, $\forall i,j\in J_n$. By theorem 17 corollary 1 section 3.6, $\forall i \in J_n$, $\exists !\alpha_i\in V$ such that $\phi(\alpha_i)=L_{\alpha_i}=L_i$. We claim $B=\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n\}$ is basis of $V$. Let $\alpha \in V$. Then $\phi(\alpha)=L_\alpha \in V^{**}$. Since $\mathrm{span}(B^{**})=V^{**}$, we have $L_\alpha$ $=\sum_{i\in J_n}a_i\cdot L_i$, for some $a_i\in F$. By theorem 17 section 3.6, $\phi:V\to V^{**}$ is isomorphism. By theorem 7 section 3.2, $\phi^{-1}$ is linear map. So $\phi^{-1}(L_\alpha)$ $=\phi^{-1}(\sum_{i\in J_n}a_i\cdot L_i)$ $=\alpha$ $= \sum_{i\in J_n}a_i\cdot \phi^{-1}(L_i)$ $= \sum_{i\in J_n}a_i\cdot \alpha_i$. Thus $\alpha \in \mathrm{span}(\{\alpha_1,…\alpha_n\})$. Hence $V=\mathrm{span}(\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n\})$. If $\sum_{i\in J_n}c_i\cdot \alpha_i=0$, for some $c_i\in F$. So $\phi (0)$ $=\phi(\sum_{i\in J_n}c_i\cdot \alpha_i)$ $= \sum_{i\in J_n}c_i\cdot \phi(\alpha_i)$ $= \sum_{i\in J_n}c_i\cdot L_{\alpha_i}$ $= \sum_{i\in J_n}c_i\cdot L_i$ $=0$. Since $B^{**}$ is independent, we have $c_i=0_F$, $\forall i\in J_n$. Thus $\{\alpha_1,…\alpha_n\}$ is independent. Hence $B=\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n\}$ is basis of $V$. We claim $B^*=\{f_1,…,f_n\}$ is dual basis of $B=\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n\}$. Let $i,j\in J_n$. Since $L_{\alpha_j}=L_j$, we have $L_j(f)$ $=L_{\alpha_j}(f)$ $=f(\alpha_j)$, $\forall f\in V^*$. In particular, $L_j(f_i)$ $=L_{\alpha_j}(f_i)$ $=f_i(\alpha_j)$. Since $L_j(f_i)=\delta_{ij}$, we have $f_i(\alpha_j)=\delta_{ij}$. Thus $f_i(\alpha_j)=\delta_{ij}$, $\forall i,j\in J_n$. Hence $B^*=\{f_1,…,f_n\}$ is dual basis of $B=\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n\}$. **Is my proof correct?**

Comment: I just realize, it is suffice to show either $\mathrm{span}(\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n\})=V$ or $\{\alpha_1,…,\alpha_n\}$ is independent, because we known $\mathrm{dim}(V)=n$.

Comment: I think your proof is correct, but between your expectation that I should have a copy of Hoffman available to look up your references, your needless introduction of multiple notations for the same objects, use of another notation ($\phi$) without any introduction at all - forcing us to guess it is the natural isomorphism, endless trivial justifications for matters already known simply from the definition of "basis", and poorly organized wall-of-text, this is very difficult to read, so it is quite possible errors are hidden in the weeds. I suggest editing for clarity and conciseness.

Comment: @PaulSinclair In that sense, I should write everything before this theorem. That would make this post “independent”. You said, I justify endless trivial facts which follows immediately from definition of basis. Can you point some few trivial justification?

Comment: It is not too much to ask that you quote the key results you are using when talking to an audience that may not have access to your source. As for one example of where you waste time justifying something trivial, You introduce $B^{**}$ as the dual basis. That $B^{**}$ is a basis is something you make use of without proving it (which is proper - I'm sure that the dual basis is a basis is something that has been proved in your course). But that fact alone is enough to say that $\phi(\alpha) = L_\alpha = \sum_i a_i L_i$. You did not need to state $\text{span}(B^{**})=V^{**}$ first.